# When is $\mathbb{Q}_X$ pure?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology, perverse-sheaves

I'll ask this question in the language of mixed Hodge modules, since that's where I'm coming from, but the question has an exact analogue for mixed l-adic complexes on schemes over fields of positive characteristic, and maybe the answer is nicer in that language.  If so, I'd love to hear it.  Anyway:

Let X be a complex algebraic variety.  Let $\mathbb{Q}$ denote the weight zero one-dimensional mixed Hodge structure/MHM-on-a-point, let $p:X\rightarrow pt$ be the map down to a point.  Denote $\mathbb{Q}_X=p^*\mathbb{Q}$ as usual.  The question is: when is $\mathbb{Q}_X$ pure?  In other words, when is there an isomorphism

$\mathbb{Q}_X\cong \bigoplus_{i\in\mathbb{Z}} \mathcal{H}^i(\mathbb{Q}_X)$

inside $D(MHM(X))$, with each $\mathcal{H}^i(\mathbb{Q}_X)$ a weight $i$ pure mixed Hodge module living in cohomological degree $i$?

The answer everyone knows is "yes, if $X$ is smooth".  Then the degree $i$ piece in the above decomposition is the restriction of $\mathbb{Q}_X$ to the $i$-dimensional components of $X$.  Over a curve it seems we can do a bit better ("yes, if $X$ has only unibranch singularities and so the intersection complex is the constant sheaf"?).  In what other cases is the answer yes?

Does the answer change if I switch to the land of mixed l-adic complexes and let $X$ be an algebraic *stack* over a field of positive characteristic?

Comment: If $X$ is the quotient $Y/G$ of a smooth variety $Y$ (or, more generally, such that $\mathbf Q_Y$ is pure) by the action of a finite group $G$, then $\mathbf Q_X$ is pure as well. For example, symmetric products are pure.